# Using aptdcon or other apps in non-interactive script(s)?

Tags: command-line, scripts

I was trying to find a way in order to use [aptdcon](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/aptdcon.1.html) -- the command line client for aptdaemon in a script.

aptdcon misses options such as:

- Loggable output - no progress indicator.
- Assume No to all queries and do not prompt.

> The following package will be upgraded (1): xxx
>
> Need to get xxx of archives.
>
> Do you want to continue [Y/n]?

So aptdcon prompts for a user response making it inappropriate for shell scripts.

How can I use aptdcon or any other app (that doesn't need root permissions) in non user-interactive scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one answered. I added my workaround to this question.

Instead of using aptdcon I use aptitude to display all the available updates in a logable/scriptable format.

```
aptitude search '~U'
```